# Численно убедиться в справедливости равенства C++

Tags: c++, математика, ряды

Полностью задача звучит так:

В следующих заданиях необходимо численно убедиться в
справедливости равенства, то есть необходимо сравнить результаты
вычисления значения функции для заданного значения аргумента,
полученные двумя способами: вычислением с использованием
стандартных математических функций (левая часть равенства) и путем
разложения функции с заданной точностью eps (правая часть равенства).
При вычислении разложения необходимо также выяснить количество
шагов разложения, потребовавшееся для достижения точности eps
[image: уравнение]

Я не понимаю что такое разложение функции, да и не силён в программировании, поэтому буду очень благодарен за подробные объяснения и примеры

Comment: Вам на сайт https://freelance.habr.com/

Comment: Много объяснений и примеров можно найти в вопросах с меткой `ряды`

Comment: Если вы примерно понимаете что такое `+ ... +`, `+ ...`, `n!`, `(2n - 1)!!`, то вы знаете как приближенно вычислить правую часть. Если нет, найдите начальный учебник или курс по теории рядов. Без представления о рядах к этой задаче не подступиться.

Answer (score 0):

Есть функция, она связывает аргумент со значением. Как именно? И как можно выразить эту связь? Берём лист бумаги и рисуем на нём график функции, теперь можно отложить на оси абсцисс аргумент, провести от этой точки линию параллельно оси ординат до пересечения с графиком, а потом от точки пересечения провести линию параллельное оси абсцисс до пересечения с осью ординат и по шкале этой оси оценить значение функции. Можно график вырезать из листа стали и упереть в него кулачок. А теперь приходит господин Тейлор и говорит:
– Я хочу посчитать эту функцию на калькуляторе.
А функция в калькуляторе не реализована. Как быть? Зовём товарища Брадиса. Брадис нам говорит:
– Для такого-то значения аргумента значение функции уже известно.
Но Тейлор упирается:
– Функция нужна для другого аргумента.
Брадис:
– Ну значения-то близки, значения функции – тоже.
Тейлор опять упирается:
– Но меня не устраивает такая точность.
Брадис:
– На этом отрезке график похож на прямую, узнай её наклон, вычисли для этого угла наклона отношение приращения ординаты к приращению абсциссы, потом умножь разность значений аргумента на это значение и сложи с известным значением функции.
– О! – говорит Тейлор. – Это будет первым членом моего разложения функции в ряд. Вот только наклон всё же меняется, а завтра я захочу ещё большую точность. Так введу-ка я следующий член, где умножу другое число уже на квадрат разности значений аргумента, чтоб учесть изменение угла наклона по мере удаления от известной точки, а ещё в следующем – на куб. И так далее. И всё это сложу. А за известное значение возьму значение функции ноля, оно будет нулевым членом моего ряда.
Они могли не встречаться. Могли не общаться даже опосредовано. Могли даже не застать калькулятор. Но суть идеи ряда данный диалог передаёт. А за подробностями идите в ВУЗ слушать курс высшей математики.